# How can i sort javascript.map array of names by ABC

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort array of first names by ABC from this javascript map.
And also i want to hide the "undefined" row from the results:

```js
function contacts_callback(obj) {
    var contactinfo = obj.contacts.map(o => 
        `${o.givenName} ${o.familyName} ${o.organizationName} ${
             o.phoneNumbers.map(n => n.phoneNumber)
        }`)
        .join("<br>");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = contactinfo;
}

// Demo
var obj = 
  {"success":true,"contacts":[
{"emailAddresses":[],"phoneNumbers":[{"label":"unknown","phoneNumber":"XXX-XXXXXXX"}],"givenName":"GGG","organizationName":"","familyName":"ggg",},
{"emailAddresses":[],"phoneNumbers":[{"label":"unknown","phoneNumber":"XXX-XXXXXXX"}],"givenName":"AAA","organizationName":"","familyName":"aaa",},
{"emailAddresses":[],"phoneNumbers":[{"label":"unknown","phoneNumber":"XXX-XXXXXXX"}],"givenName":"BBB","organizationName":"Apple","familyName":"bbb",},
{"emailAddresses":[],"phoneNumbers":[{"label":"unknown","phoneNumber":"XXX-XXXXXXX"}],"givenName":"undefined","organizationName":"","familyName":"",},
{"emailAddresses":[],"phoneNumbers":[{"label":"unknown","phoneNumber":"XXX-XXXXXXX"}],"givenName":"","organizationName":"Apple","familyName":"",},
]};

contacts_callback(obj);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Side note; having a string of "undefined" as an actual value is a code smell.  If it is undefined, it should be undefined, not a string

Comment: Use `.sort()` and `.filter()` on obj.contacts before mapping it.

Comment: Sort by which name?

Comment: @Taplar I've not heard of anybody called "Undefined", *yet* but I know people with the name `Null` have had tons of problems with a lot of systems. So, yes - it's bad to have a string for a value that *shoudln't be a string*.

Comment: I wrote "undefined" because in my Android phone if the name is empty so te result is "undefined" so I want to hide the row of this NULL name.

Comment: If that's the case, then why does the last entry have a givenName that is a blank string, rather than it being undefined as well.  The point being, "undefined" is a value.  `undefined` is not.  You should not turn lack of information, into information

Comment: I don't know, on chrome it works but in my app on an android phone a blank name gets "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the undefined name rows and sort by `givenName` and then map the wanted result.

```js
function contacts_callback(obj) {
    var contactinfo = obj.contacts
        .filter(({ givenName }) => givenName !== 'undefined')
        .sort(({ givenName: a }, { givenName: b }) => a.localeCompare(b))
        .map(({ givenName, familyName, organizationName, phoneNumbers }) => 
            `${givenName} ${familyName} ${organizationName} ${
                 phoneNumbers.map(({ phoneNumber }) => phoneNumber)
            }`)
        .join("<br>");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = contactinfo;
}

// Demo
var obj = { success: true, contacts: [{ emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "GGG", organizationName: "", familyName: "ggg" }, { emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "AAA", organizationName: "", familyName: "aaa" }, { emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "BBB", organizationName: "Apple", familyName: "bbb" }, { emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "undefined", organizationName: "", familyName: "" }, { emailAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [{ label: "unknown", phoneNumber: "XXX-XXXXXXX" }], givenName: "", organizationName: "Apple", familyName: "" }] };

contacts_callback(obj);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```